# angularjs change element based on dropdown select

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs

I have 3 select dropdowns and a button to get a json list

Focus select dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id='sort' ng-model='sort'>
  <option value='1'>ID</option>
  <option value='2'>Departmentname</option>
  <option value='3'>Number of employees</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="getinfo()">GET INFO</button>
```

The table looks like this

```
<table>
<tr> <td>{{ depid }}</td> <td>{{ depname }}</span></td> <td>{{ depemp }}</td></tr>
```

In the controller I have:

```
$scope.depid = "Department id";
$scope.depname = "Departmentname";
$scope.depemp = "Number of employees";

$scope.getinfo = function() {
  var url = "";  
  ...
}
```

Based on selection "sort" I want the sort column to be bold/strong or uppercase.

How do I do thIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) on the `td` elements:

```
<tr> 
    <td ng-class="{bold : sort == 1}">{{ depid }}</td> 
    <td ng-class="{bold : sort == 2}">{{ depname }}</span></td> 
    <td ng-class="{bold : sort == 3}">{{ depemp }}</td>
</tr>
```

And add a CSS rule:

```
.bold { 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12834/) demonstration.

Comment: After testing the header becomes bold before loading the table in the correct sort order. The change must come from within the controller. Any idea?

Comment: After the `getInfo` function set a new variable as the value of the sort... call it something like `sortedBy` so if getInfo is a promise then do `getInfoPromise.then(function(){sortedBy = sort})`

Answer (score 0):

Following Omri Aharon I changed 
    ng-class="{bold : sort == 1}" 
to 
    ng-class="{bold : sortby == 1}"
and followed Nayish I put following inside controller
    $scope.getinfo = function() {
      var url = "";
      ...
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response; 
      $scope.sortby = $scope.sort;});
    }

Thanks a lot to the two of you!